# unable to save with mongoose Model.save() - gives Internal Server Error

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mean

This is part of a MEAN app. The code execution reaches the node controller method and also creates the model object correctly(verified using console log). However, the mongoose model.save() method produces error as shown below. What could be the reason?

**method in node controller**

```
exports.addEmployee = (req, res, next) => {
  const employee = new Employee(req.body);
  console.log('backend emp ctlr - employee: ' + employee)
  employee.save()
    .then( addedEmployee => {
      res.status(201).
        json({
          message: 'Employee added.',
          employeeId: addedEmployee._id
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      res.status(500)
        .json({
          message: "Server Error in saving Employee's data!"
        });
    });
}
```

**The console log** statement in above code gives correct model object as shown below

```
backend emp ctlr - employee: {
  _id: 5f9e9ee678b4704318ebc927,
  title: 'Mr.',
  fName: 'Arjun',
  lName: 'Singh',
  desig: '',
  coEmail: 'hemantparmarh@gmail.com',
  personalEmail: '',
  mobile1: '1111122222',
  mobile2: '',
  gender: '',
  dob: null,
  qualifications: '',
  band: '',
  ctc: null,
  dateOfJoining: null,
  experienceStartDate: null,
  leftCompany: false,
  dateOfLeaving: null,
  pan: '',
  addr1: '',
  addr2: '',
  city: '',
  state: '',
  pincode: '',
  contactPersonName: '',
  contactPersonMobile: '',
  userName: ''
}
```

**Error**
[image]

Comment: Do a `console.log(err)` in the `catch` block and check what is the error.

Comment: The error is:  Error: Employee validation failed: _id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "" at path "_id"    stringValue: '""',
      messageFormat: undefined,
      kind: 'ObjectId',
      value: '',
      path: '_id',
      reason: Error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters    ---  how do i resolve this error?

Comment: Based on the error message it looks like the employee object has an _id with values as an empty string (`_id: ''`). So mongoose fails to cast it to a valid ObjectId. Can you please check if `req.body` has an `_id` field with the value as an empty string

Comment: the req.body does not have _id becasue this is a new document getting created. But using the req.body a new mongoose model object is created in the first line of controller method, `const employee = new Employee(req.body);` . And this object has _id as seen in the `console.log` result - in the original post.

Comment: You were right Vishnu about `_id=""` in `req.body`. There was a hidden input field in the form for _id field. This was kept to handle the case when the same form was being used to update an employee record. I have removed it and now am able to save the document. But I am not sure how a new _id was getting assigned because  of this line `const employee = new Employee(req.body);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to save an object with an `_id` bad generated (empty string for example) the error will be thrown.

If you want to autogenerate te `_id` you have to not insert into object.

So, for example, an object like this:

```json
{
  _id: "",
  name: "Name"
}
```

Will fail when try to save.

But the same object in this way:

```json
{
  name: "Name"
}
```

Will be inserted with an autogenerated `_id`.

If you want to create your own `ObjectId` before `save` you can use `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`, which accepts a string by parameter (the string should has a correct format).

If your `req.body` object has an empty field `_id` this should work:

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

req.body._id = mongoose.Types.ObjectId()
```

After that, you can `save` the object.

Comment: The `req.body` did have an empty `_id`, but when i created a model object in the first line of controller method, it added a value to `_id` field. And then after that the mongoose model.save() method did not work. When I removed the `_id` from `req.body` the code worked.

Comment: The value added in the first line of controller is a valid ```_id``` format? How is your mongoose schema? Either ```_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId``` or not indicate ```_id``` field should works.
By the way, if ```req.body``` always contains an empty ```_id``` field, it could be a good practice not include the field.

Comment: mongoose schema does not have `_id` field. I was not clear about the behavior of `_id` field earlier. Now I think I know how it works. :)

Comment: That's nice :). Now please, if the error has been resolved, accept the answer for the rest of the community.